# Is it possible to run TFS 2008 and TFS 2010 on the same server?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010, tfs-2008

We've got a server with TFS2008 that we do all our builds on. I need to get an install of TFS2010 running. Can I run it on the same server (windows 2003) or do I need it on a seperate one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

The exact question was asked before in the MSDN Forum and you can read all the answers [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfssetup/thread/9ae032b0-0115-4477-acdb-e83cf5ec2ae4).

> As Arun said TFS 2010 installer checks
>   if previous version of TFS is
>   installed on the computer and will not
>   let you install TFS 2010 if previous
>   version is detected.
>
> There are many reasons why it is not possible to
>   install TFS 2008 and TFS 2010 side by
>   side. One of them is the fact that
>   both are creating an IIS web site with
>   the same name - "Team Foundation
>   Server".
>
> Regards,
>   --Vladimir